# Pyviz Panel Examples Returning Attribute Errors

Tags: python, panel, pyviz

Working through the Panel user guide - any example on this page (https://panel.pyviz.org/user_guide/Components.html) that uses .extend does not seem to be working and is returning

```
AttributeError: 'Tabs' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

And the gridspec example returns:

```
AttributeError: module 'panel' has no attribute 'GridSpec'
```

Currently using Panel 0.3.1

Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panel is currently at 0.6 (https://anaconda.org/pyviz/panel), and 0.3.1 won't support any of the more recent additions. So you should definitely upgrade, at which point it should match the website. If you do want to run the old version, just use the examples included with the package, which will match what's available in that version.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is a version issue: I am using v.0.6.2 and running the following example:

```
radio_group = pn.widgets.RadioButtonGroup(name='Radio Button Group',
                                          options=['Biology', 'Chemistry', 'Physics'],
                                          button_type='success')
radio_group
```

also yields the same kind of error:

```
AttributeError: 'RadioButtonGroup' object has no attribute 'value'
```